# Match header values from one file to list of files in R

Tags: r, loops, read.table

I have a folder with thousands of data files (no labels, just column numbers). I also have a CSV with a list of 1) file names from the folder, 2) column header number, and 3) column label. **Number 3 is what I need!** The data columns in the files are **not** in the same order. So I would like to match up the correct column name to each data file and bind them together by matching them (like a lookup table, but for a header).

here is the "lookup header" dummy data:

```
filenames <- c("file1", "file1", "file1","file2","file2", "file2", "file3", "file3", "file3")
num <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
label <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB", "CC", "BB", "CC", "AA")
header <- data.frame(filenames,num,label)

> header
   filenames num label
1     file1   1    AA
2     file1   2    BB
3     file1   3    CC
4     file2   1    AA
5     file2   2    BB
6     file2   3    CC
7     file3   1    BB
8     file3   2    CC
9     file3   3    AA
```

Here's  what the files look like:

```
> file1
 1      2     3
 2.3   1.5   202.4

> file2
 1     2      3
2.1   1.0   200.8

> file3
  1      2     3
 1.0   208.1  2.1
```

Then I loop through these files in my directory and bind them together based on the column name.

```
files <- dir("my dir")
z <- NULL

for (file in files) {
  x <- read.table(file.path("my dir", file), as.is=TRUE)
  names(x) <- c("AA","BB","CC") #this is where I'd like to name according to matching column
  z <- rbind(z,x) #bind current file to previous processed file
}
```

Desired Outcome from all three files!

```
> z

AA    BB    CC
2.3   1.5   202.4
2.1   1.0   200.8
2.1   1.0   208.1
```

Answer (score 0):

We get the values of the 'file' objects (assume that it is in the global environment) with `mget`, `split` the 'header' by the 'filenames' column, with `map2` (from `purrr`) `match` the column names with the 'num' column in 'y' to the set the column names with the corresponding 'label'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(paste0('file', 1:3)) %>%
     map2_df(., header %>%
                 split(factor(.$filenames, levels = unique(.$filenames))),
                    ~ set_names(.x, .y$label[match(names(.x), .y$num)]))
#   AA  BB    CC
#1 2.3 1.5 202.4
#2 2.1 1.0 200.8
#3 2.1 1.0 208.1
```

Comment: Thank you ! Instead of using `paste`, is there a way to pull in file names from "files"? In this example they are labeled "file1", "file2", but in reality, they have very long names and there are thousands. Would like it to be reproducible for many files.

Comment: @kslayerr  If you have only those objects loaded into the session, then `ls()` and if those have some pattern in names `mget(ls(pattern ="file\\d+"))`

Comment: I list all files in the directory as "files" before I loop through them. They each start with the same alphanumeric beginning, then are separated by "_" and a date.